# How to communicate different levels in the same javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, javascript-objects

I am trying to namespace my jQuery app.

Example:

```
var app = {
    data : {
     data1: ''
   },
   fn: {
    setData1: function(value){
      app.data.data1 = value
    }
  }  
}
```

This works, but is there a better solution which doesn't use the full path? Moreover, is this a good code structure for a medium-sized application?

Comment: Did the answer below solve your issue? If so, please mark an accepted answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate to the community that your question has been answered and then both you and the person who provided the answer will earn some reputation points that can lead to more privileges here on StackOverflow.  If your question is still unanswered, then please explain what else you are confused about.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not have syntax for specifying shortcuts to a parent element in a nested literal object definition.  And, in fact, Javascript a nested object inside another object could have been defined anywhere and the reference assigned into the object and could be assigned into many objects so there is no real such thing as a parent at runtime as far as Javascript is concerned.  Javascript just doesn't work that way.

As such, if you want to reference another element of the object that is not below it, then you will have to use the full path of object names starting from the top of the object.

As to whether this is a good way to do this, that is entirely context-specific.  At first glance (and with no other context supplied), I don't see why you need the `fn` or `data` levels in your object.  Data properties and methods can be at the same level and that is commonly done without adding extra levels.  You will find that extra levels that aren't necessary just increase the amount of typing in your code and do not improve performance.  You should give your methods and data properties meaningful enough names that it's very clear what they are and what they are used for.  A name like `data1` is not a particularly good example.

In addition, there is generally not a reason to make a `setData1()` method for a public `data1` property, but if you put them at the same level, you can do use the `this` pointer in the method which will be set to `app` if someone calls `app.setData1()`:

```
var app = {
     data1: ''
     setData1: function(value){
          this.data1 = value;
    }
}
```